# Why do I need to deal with Captcha while logged in?

Tags: support

The Captcha feature is really freaking annoying. This is the only thing that is really making my experience in the site less than enjoyable. It fails most of the time.

Comment: I also hate the captcha, but it's worth mentioning that "logging in" is just a cookie and it's easy to write a script that does that (e.g. it's just a few extra parameters to wget).

Comment: I'm getting used to it. The captcha only kicks in if I edit a question multiple times in a short period.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce having to insert captcha while logged in. [That's a **rate limiting mechanism.**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html)

I can't reproduce the consistent failures you are facing. Is it due to problems in typing in the correct response or does reCaptcha expect a completely different response?

Comment: Is not a typing issue, since I could confirm a captcha successfully once and unsuccessfully other times, even when typing the same words. Usually I have to change the captcha several times before being able to complete.

Comment: Looks like if you enter a captcha and it is accepted, next time you try to validate another post with the same captcha it fails, but the system doesn't show a different captcha by default. Is that normal?

Comment: No, in my experience implementing reCAPTCHA in other web services, seeing the same image twice in a row is a caching issue on the part of the web client or server. Quick fix would be to always click the "refresh" icon in reCAPTCHA before you enter the text. That way you're sure you have a fresh image from their server.